# Will searching for a subview with a private API class name be rejected?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, app-store-connect, iphone-privateapi

Apple recently introduced the `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` for `UICollectionViews` which are amazing. Their only limitation is that when setting the `orthogonalScrollingBehavior` to `continuous`, the scroll view delegate methods and `contentOffset` of the collectionView are missing as the "scrolling behaviour" is accomplished with a totally different scroll view not given to the user.

For a non-essential pure nicety feature I need to access the `contentOffset` of the collection view which is always `(0, 0)` when using the new `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`. However if I simply get the abstracted away `UIScrollView` then I can check the `contentOffset` and make the necessary calculation with it.

My code to achieve this:

```
let view = collectionView.subviews.first(where: { view in
  return String(describing: type(of: view)) == "_UICollectionViewOrthogonalScrollerEmbeddedScrollView"
})

return view as? UIScrollView
```

I am aware that this may change tomorrow and break this code upon a new version of iOS being released. As I said this is mostly a nicety feature that I would really like to have but it is mostly inessential to the rest of the app. That aside, will this get me rejected for "using" private APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [visibleItemsInvalidationHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutsection/3199096-visibleitemsinvalidationhandler) to get contentOffset

```
layoutSection.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = ({ (visibleItems, point, env) in
         print(point)
    })
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of this solution at the time!